# Передача между фунциями jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ребят подскажите плез как передать массив между ф-иями jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var change = [...];// этот массив
...      
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
//передать сюда
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var change = [...];// этот массив
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...      
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  //передать сюда
  console.log(change);
});
```

или

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var change = [...];// этот массив
  ...      

  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    //передать сюда
    console.log(change);
  });
});
```